# Android ListView Item Overlapping Effekt

Tags: android, listview, alpha, overlapping

**Hello, I would like to create the following ListView Effekt:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge0xt.png

The ListView should have max 5 rows and every row should have a different alpha value.

**Now I just need the overlapping effect for the past task.**

I just created the following code for the alpha effect.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tKjl.png

```
if((schedule.getCurrentPosition()-1) == position){
        rowView.setAlpha(.5f);
    }

    if(schedule.getCurrentPosition() == position){
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_search_url_text_holo));
        rowView.setAlpha(1f);
    }

    if((schedule.getCurrentPosition() + 1) == position){
        rowView.setAlpha(.5f);
    }

    if((schedule.getCurrentPosition() + 2) == position){
        rowView.setAlpha(.25f);
    }

    if((schedule.getCurrentPosition() + 3) == position){
        rowView.setAlpha(.15f);
    }
```

**Now I just need the overlapping effect for the past task.**

Comment: please add your current ListView code to this post so someone can help you add the alpha effect to it.

Comment: you can use a ninepatch image for this purpose.